# I have uploaded a picture in stack overflow. But I cannot see it now

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

The profile picture which I have uploaded through my home pc is not getting reflected in my profile in stackoverflow. Any probable reasons for this? Is there a normal delay?

I also don't see profile picture of other users.

Comment: Are you talking about [this picture](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1641086/krsna-chaitanya) in your profile?

Comment: Yes. I'm not able to see any pic. Are you able to see any pic ?

Comment: I can see a picture of a man in a blue shirt and sunglasses.

Comment: Are you not able to see that picture anywhere (including Stack Overflow) or are you not able to see it on specific sites (like Meta, Stack Apps, and Unix/Linux)?

Comment: Could imgur.com be blocked on your system?

Comment: may be my office network has blocked the pic

Comment: @RichardTingle, you have answered the question :)

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya - Can you see your pic on here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q7LSy.jpg?s=128&g=1 ?

Comment: What do you see?  A broken image?  Or your gravatar?

Comment: And can you see **anyones** profile picture?

Comment: And can you see the image in @him056 [profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through the following checklist:

1. Confirm that `imgur.com` is not blocked by your ISP.
2. Clear your browser's cache.
3. Check if the image in following block-quote is visible or not:

   > [image: img]
4. If possible, use gravtar.

Comment: imgur.com is blocked on my system

Comment: How come I'm able to see other pics. I'm able to see others' profile pics like BalusC

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya That is hosted on gravtar.com `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/89927e2f4bde24991649b353a37678b9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG`

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm that your picture is there, and that you look positively dashing. It appears that, unfortunately, imgur.com is blocked at your office.

This means that you don't get to look at cat gifs all day, [and are therefore less productive](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20121008/14334820644/study-viewing-cat-videos-work-can-make-you-more-productive.shtml). Someone should do something about that.

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow images (profile pictures, pictures in posts) are hosted at imgur.com. Image hosting services including imgur.com are often blocked on corporate networks and this may well be the difficulty for you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The profile picture I uploaded wasn't appearing anywhere besides the page where I uploaded it. After trying lots of other things, I noticed there is a `Save Profile` button way down at the bottom of the page. I uploaded yet again, then pressed the `Save Profile` button and the problem was fixed! Doh!

Comment: Why did this get down voted? I thought it might help someone. It would have helped me!

Comment: This is not relevant. In the case of this question, it's about not seeing any profile picture using imgur as the host. The OP mentioned it in a comment, I've now added this to the question itself to prevent future confusion.

Comment: You shouldn't down vote a legitimate answer and then make your question more specific. That's just rude.

Comment: I did not downvote, I explained the likely reason.